# Mac Catalyst net maui KeyChain

Tags: macos, mac-catalyst, maui

I'm trying to access the keychain to get the installed certificates, but it always returns null.

I installed the pfx certificate on my macOS, but in the code output it says "item not found".

```
SecRecord rec = new(SecKind.Certificate);
 SecStatusCode code;
 SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(rec, out code);
 NSData[] nsDatas = SecKeyChain.QueryAsData(rec, false, 999, out code);
 if (nsDatas != null)
 {
     foreach (NSData item in nsDatas)
     {
         X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(item.ToArray());
         x509Certificate2s.Add(cert);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Someone answered the question on github : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7126#issuecomment-1126147716 , `Looks like this is a restriction in Mac Catalyst`.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT The problem is that I can't do it with Mac Catalyst